# Refresh ListView But on background page

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have Two files 1. Companies page where im showing companies in list view and I'm adding new companies to this via a dialog box which is a different file 2. add_Company.dart.
After I add a new company, i need to refresh the background companies listView for the new company added without closing the dialog box.
Companies.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import './Object.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';
import './Detail_Pages/Company_details.dart';
import './Add object Popup/add_company.dart';

class Companies extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CompaniesState createState() => _CompaniesState();
}

class _CompaniesState extends State<Companies> {
  void changeScreen(BuildContext context, Widget widget) {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => widget));
  }

  Future<List<Company>> _getCompanies() async {
    var data = await http.get("http://localhost/crm_demo/getData.php");
    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);
    List<Company> companies = [];
    for (var c in jsonData) {
      Company company = Company(
          c["name"],
          c["address"],
          c["opportunities"],
          c["pipelineRevenue"],
          c["revenueAchieved"],
          c["city"],
          c["state"],
          c["country"],
          c["zipcode"],
          c["phone"],
          c["timezone"],
          c["tags"]);
      companies.add(company);
    }
    return companies;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(
            "Companies",
            style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
          ),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  showDialog(
                      barrierDismissible: false,
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return Dialog(
                          elevation: 10.0,
                          child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                              child: AddCompanyAction()),
                        );
                      });
                })
          ],
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder(
            future: _getCompanies(),
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                return ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return Card(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5.0, 5.0, 5.0, 0.0),
                          child: ExpansionTile(
                            leading: InkWell(
                              onTap: () {
                                Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                        builder: (context) => CompanyDetails(
                                            company: snapshot.data[index])));
                              },
                              child: CircleAvatar(
                                  radius: 20.0,
                                  child: Text(snapshot.data[index].name[0])),
                            ),
                            title: InkWell(...),
                            subtitle: Flexible(...),
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Container(
                                  child: Column(...),
                                  Row(
                                    children: [
                                      Column(...)
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ],
                              ))
                            ],
                          ));
                    });
              } else {
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                );
              }
            }));
  }

  Widget companyLabels(String values) {...}

  Widget companyValues(String values) {...}
```

add_company.dart (the dialog where i add a new company)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class AddCompanyAction extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _AddCompanyActionState createState() => _AddCompanyActionState();
}

class _AddCompanyActionState extends State<AddCompanyAction> {
  TextEditingController compName = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController compAddress1 = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController compAddress2 = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController compCity = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController compState = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController compCountry = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController compZipcode = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController compPhone = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController compTimezone = new TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController compTags = new TextEditingController();

  void addData() {
    String compname = compName.text.toString();
    String compaddress1 = compAddress1.text.toString();
    String compaddress2 = compAddress2.text.toString();
    String compcity = compCity.text.toString();
    String compstate = compState.text.toString();
    String compcountry = compCountry.text.toString();
    String compzipcode = compZipcode.text.toString();
    String compphone = compPhone.text.toString();
    String comptimezone = compTimezone.text.toString();
    String comptags = compTags.text.toString();

    var url = "http://localhost/crm_demo/addData.php";
    http.post(url, body: {
      "name": compname,
      "address": "$compaddress1" + " " + "$compaddress2",
      "opportunities": "5",
      "pipelineRevenue": "50000",
      "revenueAchieved": "4500",
      "city": compcity,
      "state": compstate,
      "country": compcountry,
      "zipcode": compzipcode,
      "phone": compphone,
      "timezone": comptimezone,
      "tags": comptags,
    });
  }

  void clearFields() {
    compName.clear();
    compAddress1.clear();
    compAddress2.clear();
    compCity.clear();
    compState.clear();
    compCountry.clear();
    compZipcode.clear();
    compPhone.clear();
    compTimezone.clear();
    compTags.clear();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Text('Add a new company'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.close),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(context);
              })
        ],
      ),
      body: ListView(
        children: [
          Flexible(
              child:
                  Textfields("Enter a Company name", "Company Name", compName)),
          Flexible(
              child: Textfields(
                  "No / Street / Lane", "Address line 1", compAddress1)),
          Flexible(
              child: Textfields(
                  "Area / State / Country", "Address line 2", compAddress2)),
          Row(children: [
            Flexible(child: Textfields("Enter City name", "City", compCity)),
            Flexible(
                child: Textfields("Enter State number", "State", compState))
          ]),
          Row(children: [
            Flexible(
                child:
                    Textfields("Enter Country name", "Country", compCountry)),
            Flexible(
                child: Textfields("Enter Zipcode", "Zipcode", compZipcode)),
          ]),
          Flexible(
              child: Textfields(
                  "Enter Company's Phone number", "Phone Number", compPhone)),
          Flexible(
              child: Textfields("Enter Timezone", "Timezone", compTimezone)),
          Container(
            child: Text(""),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0, right: 20.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                Builder(
                  builder: (context) {
                    return Container(
                        child: MaterialButton(
                      child: Text("Save"),
                      onPressed: () {
                        var cc = compName.text;
                        if (cc != "") {
                          addData();
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            content: Text('Company $cc is added'),
                          ));
                        }
                        clearFields();
                      },
                      color: Colors.blue,
                    ));
                  },
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 10),
                MaterialButton(
                  child: Text("Cancel"),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop(context);
                  },
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Textfields extends StatelessWidget {
  final String hint;
  final String label;
  final TextEditingController controllerName;

  const Textfields(this.hint, this.label, this.controllerName);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, top: 20.0, right: 10.0),
      height: 50,
      child: TextField(
          controller: controllerName,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15.0),
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey, width: 1.2)),
            hintText: hint,
            labelText: label,
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue, width: 1.2)),
          )),
    );
  }
}
```

Im new to flutter, would really help if you tell me how to implement. Thanks in advance for going over the code.

Comment: you need to get a callback with new added company name from companiesDialog in listView screen and setState in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass a `Function` to your dialog widget that you can call on add.

```dart
class AddCompanyAction extends StatefulWidget {
  final void Function() callback;

  const AddCompanyAction({@required this.callback});
  @override
  _AddCompanyActionState createState() => _AddCompanyActionState();
}
```

then do the following in `onPressed`

```dart
                      onPressed: () {
                        
                        var cc = compName.text;
                        if (cc != "") {
                          addData();
                          Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
                            content: Text('Company $cc is added'),
                          ));
                        }
                        clearFields();

                        // The Function
                        widget.callback();
                      },
```

Pass the callback in your `Companies.dart` like this:

```dart
                        return Dialog(
                          elevation: 10.0,
                          child: Container(
                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
                              child: AddCompanyAction(
                                callback: () => _getCompanies(),
                              )),
                        );
                      });
```

In my experience this should, but should you run into any troubles feel free to comment.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked. Note - i had to wrap _getCompanies() inside setState() to achieve the refreshing.